Как в слайдере стилизовать слайд, идущий перед центральным?
Есть задача сделать слайдер из пяти активных слайдов: центральный - крупный, по бокам от него - чуть меньшего размера, крайние - стандартного. На чистом css получается стилизовать только центральный и следующий за ним:


let owl = $('.owl-carousel');

owl.owlCarousel({
  center: true,
  items: 5,
  loop: true,
  nav: true
});
.container {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
.slider {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.slide {
  padding: 50px 0;
  transition: .5s;
}
.slide img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.owl-item.center {
  transform: scale(1.5) !important;
  transition: .3s;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.owl-item.center + .owl-item {
  transform: scale(1.25);
  transition: .3s;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="slider owl-carousel">
    <div class="slide"><img src="https://s1.1zoom.ru/big3/421/343461-svetik.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="https://s1.1zoom.ru/big3/421/343461-svetik.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="https://s1.1zoom.ru/big3/421/343461-svetik.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="https://s1.1zoom.ru/big3/421/343461-svetik.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="https://s1.1zoom.ru/big3/421/343461-svetik.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="https://s1.1zoom.ru/big3/421/343461-svetik.jpg" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</div>



Пробовал с помощью js добавлять предыдущему слайду класс и стилизовать таким образом, но работает это дело криво - класс при перелистывании слайдера добавляется другому элементу:

/а здесь в сниппете почему-то вообще ничего не добавляется/


let owl = $('.owl-carousel');

owl.owlCarousel({
  center: true,
  items: 5,
  loop: true,
  nav: true
});

$('.owl-item.active.center').prev().addClass('prev');

owl.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event) {
  $('.owl-item').removeClass('prev');
  $('.owl-item.active.center').prev().addClass('prev');
});
.container {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
.slider {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.slide {
  padding: 50px 0;
  transition: .5s;
}
.slide img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.owl-item.center {
  transform: scale(1.5) !important;
  transition: .3s;
  position: relative !important;
  z-index: 2;
}
.owl-item.center + .owl-item,
.owl-item.prev {
  transform: scale(1.25);
  transition: .3s;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="slider owl-carousel">
    <div class="slide"><img src="https://s1.1zoom.ru/big3/421/343461-svetik.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="https://s1.1zoom.ru/big3/421/343461-svetik.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="https://s1.1zoom.ru/big3/421/343461-svetik.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="https://s1.1zoom.ru/big3/421/343461-svetik.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="https://s1.1zoom.ru/big3/421/343461-svetik.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="https://s1.1zoom.ru/big3/421/343461-svetik.jpg" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</div>



Подскажите, как можно стилизовать предыдущий от центрального слайд?

Так у предыдущего слайда есть класс уникальный prev. На него вешайте - transform: scale(1.25)

@ЕвгенийЛи, нету у него такого класса - посмотрите мой скрин (или выполните код и гляньте в отладчике)

Вот держи. Костыль конечно конкретный, но что поделаешь. В стилях последние строки добавил, сравнишь с старым кодом и поймёшь, что я добавил)). Z-index сам допишешь после центрового который, времени нет поправлять.


let owl = $('.owl-carousel');

owl.owlCarousel({
  center: true,
  items: 5,
  loop: true,
  nav: true
});

$('.owl-item.active.center').prev().addClass('prev');

owl.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event) {
  $('.owl-item').removeClass('prev');
  $('.owl-item.active.center').prev().addClass('prev');
});
.container {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
.slider {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.slide {
  padding: 50px 0;
  transition: .5s;
}
.slide img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.owl-item.center {
  transform: scale(1.5) !important;
  transition: .3s;
  position: relative !important;
  z-index: 3;
}
.owl-item.center + .owl-item,
.owl-item.active + .owl-item {
  transform: scale(1.25);
  transition: .3s;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.owl-item.center + .owl-item + .owl-item, .owl-item.center + .owl-item + .owl-item + .owl-item {
  transform: scale(1);
  z-index: 1;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="slider owl-carousel">
    <div class="slide"><img src="https://s1.1zoom.ru/big3/421/343461-svetik.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="https://s1.1zoom.ru/big3/421/343461-svetik.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="https://s1.1zoom.ru/big3/421/343461-svetik.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="https://s1.1zoom.ru/big3/421/343461-svetik.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="https://s1.1zoom.ru/big3/421/343461-svetik.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="https://s1.1zoom.ru/big3/421/343461-svetik.jpg" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</div>




Да, это работает, спасибо! Если никто не предложит более элегантного варианта, приму Ваш ответ.
